# Starting elements get lost while unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

Good morning,
I'm trying to find a mistake in our code regarding unmarshalling XML using JAXB when the xml is **NOT** pritty formated. I've done quite a lot of debugging and tests but still can't find the error.

The explizit part of the xml looks like the following:

```
<list>
  <m note="m1"><g><data /><adress /></g><e><data /><adress /></e></m>
  <m note="m2"><g><data /><adress /></g><e><data /><adress /></e></m>
  <m note="m3"><g><data /><adress /></g><e><data /><adress /></e></m>      
</list>
```

The list can contain up to 50.000 `<m>` elements, thats why we don't unmarshal the whole list at once, but every single `<m>` element.

For this we have the below code. The creation of the unmarshaller is moved to an interface to differ between elements we want to unmarshal via jaxb including subelements (like the `m` element and those (like the `<list>`element) where we only read the attributes manually. In case of an `<m>` element a normal jaxb-unmarshaller is used.

**proceeding method**

```
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(xmlInputReader);

while (reader.hasNext()) {
  // Check for start elements
  int type = reader.next();
  if (type == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
    
    // Create unmarshaller 
    String elementName = reader.getLocalName();
    LOG.trace("Create unmarshaller for element: {}", elementName);
    IUnmarshaller<?> unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller(elementName);

    LOG.trace("Unmarshal Element");
    JAXBElement<?> element = unmarshaller.unmarshall(reader);

    // proceeding the element
    proceed(element);
    }
  }
}
```

For full detailes the unmarshaller implementation which is used for the `<m>` elements

```
public class BindingUnmarshallerImpl implements IUnmarshaller {

  private Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;
  private Class c = null;

  public BindingUnmarshallerImpl(JAXBContext context, Class c) throws JAXBException {
    this.unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    this.c = c;
  }

  @Override
  public JAXBElement unmarshall(XMLStreamReader reader) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBElement jaxb = null;
    jaxb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader, c);
    return jaxb;
  }
}
```

So coming the problem: The code above works well, when in the xml every `<m>` element is on a own row. If this is the case three `<m>` elements including their subelements are unmarshalled and proceeded.
In this case the log looks like this

> Create unmarshaller for element: m
>
> Create unmarshaller for element: m
>
> Create unmarshaller for element: m

This means all three `m` elements are found and unmarshalled correctly

But when there are several `<m>`-elements in the same row (no matters if thre are spaces between them or not) it breaks. Given the following XML

```
<list>
  <m note="m1"><g><data /><adress /></g><e><data /><adress /></e></m><m note="m2"><g><data /><adress /></g><e><data /><adress /></e></m>
  <m note="m3"><g><data /><adress /></g><e><data /><adress /></e></m>      
</list>
```

Only two of the `<m>` elements (`m1` and `m3`) are unmarshalled, while the `m2` is not. Viewing the logs show that starting event of the second `m` element is not found

In this case the log looks like this

> Create unmarshaller for element: m
>
> Create unmarshaller for element: g
>
> Create unmarshaller for element: data
>
> Create unmarshaller for element: adress
>
> Create unmarshaller for element: e
>
> Create unmarshaller for element: data
>
> Create unmarshaller for element: adress
>
> Create unmarshaller for element: m

For me this looked like the reader doesn't recognizes the second `m` element. While debugging I changed the code to just print out the names of the `START_ELEMENT` and `END_ELEMENT` events from the reader, without unmarshalling anything. It looked like this:

> Start element m
>
> Start element g
>
> Start element data
>
> End element data
>
> Start element adress
>
> End element adress
>
> End element g
>
> Start element e
>
> Start element data
>
> End element data
>
> Start element adress
>
> End element adress
>
> End element e
>
> End element m
>
> Start element m
>
> Start element g
>
> Start element data
>
> End element data
>
> Start element adress
>
> End element adress
>
> End element g
>
> Start element e
>
> Start element data
>
> End element data
>
> Start element adress
>
> End element adress
>
> End element e
>
> End element m
>
> Start element m
>
> Start element g
>
> Start element data
>
> End element data
>
> Start element adress
>
> End element adress
>
> End element g
>
> Start element e
>
> Start element data
>
> End element data
>
> Start element adress
>
> End element adress
>
> End element e
>
> End element m

This showed that the reader works correct when there is no unmarshalling, but if we unmarshal the `m` elements every second `m` element on a line is not read by the reader, but must be lost while unmarshalling. This behavior can be seen with any number of `m` elements on a line. When there are six elements, the first, third and fifth element are recognized, but the other three are not and so on.

I hope you could follow my explanation and maybe anyone has an idea why this happens.

The error occurs on both WAS 8.0 (with java 1.6) and also on WAS 8.5 (java 1.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when JAXB unmarshalls, it finally moves the reader to the new `START_ELEMENT` (the second `m` element).
Then, in the new iteration of your cycle, you do `reader.next()` once again. This probably breaks your unmarshalling process. I'm not 100% sure as you don't show complete logs, but I'd check the position of reader in a debugger after marshalling

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts - I could smash the bug by set a marker when the element was unmarshaled with JAXB and when not. If the previous was unmarshaled with it I don't call the `reader.getNext` but `reader.getElementType` for type decision and all works fine, regardless of line breaks or any other stuff.